# How do I unit or UI test a URL scheme on iOS

Tags: ios, xctest, url-scheme, uitest

I gave my iOS app a URL scheme.

Is it possible to somehow test it either in a unit test or uitest?

Comment: Test what about it, precisely?

Comment: That it works? Is it possible to write a test that fires the open url to the OS and verifies that the app is started and performs the implemented actions?

Comment: "and verifies that the app is started" If the app _ex hypothesi_ isn't running when the test starts, this can hardly be a unit test or UI test belonging to this app, can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Duncan is right. Manual test is possible. But I wasn't clear enough as I meant automatic tests.
As Matt states it's not actually possible to test whether the app starts.

But i managed to do automatic as follows:

So I implemented a url scheme handler (service class), that I call right away, when the app is started from a url scheme.

Then I can unit test this class, and that it takes the expected action upon different url schemes. (i.e. pushing certain view controllers etc.)

I suppose this is sufficient to verify that my url schemes cause the expected actions.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno about unit testing, but you can certainly enter a URL with that scheme in mobile Safari and make sure that it opens your app and that your app takes the proper action.